# How to create additional gpg keyring

Tags: gnupg, public-key

I have public and private keyring files in my `.gnupg` directory (`pubring.gpg` and `secring.gpg`). I want to create a *new* keyring `trustedkeys.gpg`, also in `.gnupg`, to which I can add other people's public keys.

How do I create this new keyring?

Comment: The convention is to have *all* keys in your `pubring`. Trust is marked using GnuPG's own settings.

Comment: `gpgv` expects signatures to be in `trustedkeys.gpg`.

Comment: Can you work around the problem by making a symlink from `trustedkeys.gpg` to `pubring.gpg` (or `trusteddb.pgp`)?

Comment: @grawity conventions are just that - conventions. the OP out there will know better the needs at hand.

Comment: A use case I can think for this is to have "people" you trust in one keyring and another keyring for organizations' software signing keys.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

tested with gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.26:

```
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring trustedkeys.gpg --fingerprint
```

beginners' hint: you can use any filename not just `trustedkeys.gpg`.

it will say ``` gpg: keyring ``</path>/.gnupg/trustedkeys.gpg' created ```

to use:

```
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring trustedkeys.gpg <your-gpg-commands-here>
```

Answer (score 5):

`gpg --export KEY1 KEY2 > trustedkeys.gpg` for public keys and:

`gpg --export-secret-keys KEY1 KEY2 > trustedkeys.gpg` for complete keys (including private part).

Where you can supply (partial) fingerprints for KEY1, KEY2 etc.

Answer (score 5):

```
gpg --keyring pubring.gpg --export KEY > /tmp/exported.key
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring=path/to/new-keyring.gpg --import /tmp/exported.key
```

If you want the keyring to also be used by GPG by default from then on, as you say, omit the `--no-default-keyring` switch.

Find more information in `gpg(1)` manual under `--keyring` option.